How can I get my computer (macOS) to reference the proper spelling of medical terminology to enable proper autocorrect & spell check?
I am using MacOS and need to write documents which use a lot of medical terminology. Currently, the system detects many of these words as being incorrectly spelled (even when they are not), or invalid (when they are), and the various Autocorrect, Autocomplete, Spell Checker, and the system Dictionary all regularly try to "correct" these words, or, because they don't actually know which word I'm trying to write, cannot help me write them correctly.
I want to do more than just tell the OS to ignore these. While improper auto-corrections can be a big problem, the red underlines everywhere are very annoying as well.
I need to use these words throughout MacOS, on Mail, Messages, Calendar, Notes, Reminders, Safari, Stickies, and also in 3rd party apps running on MacOS, such as MS Office and the Chrome browser.
How can I bulk import words or entire dictionaries into the MacOS dictionary such that those words will be used by the system for auto-correction, auto-completion, spell-check, and other helpers the OS tries to provide?
I suppose related to this is the question of whether these 3rd party apps use the OS-wide dictionary or not. I do not know whether this is the case.
This is a significant problem to me, and I am willing to try just about anything to solve it, including learning Terminal if I must.

I'm sorry, are you just having issues with a spellcheck dictionary? "...fix its inability to properly interact with medical terminology" is a very awkward phrase that is confusing. Also, if you're asking for a multi-platform solution, why are you focused on MacOS? Please EDIT your post. Get rid of the heading styles. Just use regular bold and normal text and other basic formatting. The heading styles detract from the readability of your post.

Ubiquitous solution - no. There are medical dictionaries for MS Office.

@music2myear Edited to improve explanation & address feedback

@Gilby Edited to elaborate. Ok, I won't get my hopes up for a panacea. Could you tell me more about these dictionaries for MS Office? Do you know if that something that could be done for other apps as well, on an app by app basis I assume?

This revisions was honestly so poorly formatted, I am actually shocked, anyone attempt to fix it for you.  I am telling you that, so you understand, the reason you received the feedback on the formatting of your question.  Could the feedback have been worded differently, certainly, but the formatting was really really bad.

@Ramhound - You're right. I've never posted before and I just got caught up in all the formatting options. Mokubai was generous to attempt to fix my post, I said as much sincerely, but now his comments, my comment, and his edit title are all gone. They may have seen an "abomination", but I still appreciate their help. Was my first try "really bad", yes. Was the 2nd "really" needed, maybe<probably. Messages received loud and clear. No more 10y+ members need to tell me(<10h) the same thing, I got it. In the end, my final draft is much much much better. You told me, I understand.

Dictionaries for Office: Web search finds more than one. Have a search and try. I expect: some may not work with Office on a Mac, and the more expensive the better (probably).

@Gilby - Thank you, that is helpful. I'll look into it. Is there a more technical term for this sort of thing, or is it just a "dictionary"? Does this mean that a folder would also be called a dictionary if it contained data on an entire foreign language?

I just did a search for "microsoft word medical dictionary". I think "dictionary" is the  technical term :). But I have never had a need for a medical dictionary.

@Gilby - Thanks -- Well, if you should ever need to export your medical or insurance records to an editable document, maybe this could help. Especially in your case, I wish there was a multi-app dictionary or another one for pdfs just to get definitions. -- I mostly need this to write, but reading matters too, I'll never be 100% fluent, the language system is crazy. -- I need my computer to stop autocorrecting these terms, it's dangerous, and a huge pain. My bad spelling is much safer than the wrong word.

I think a question that COULD be answered is how to bulk import words to a MS Word (on Mac OS) dictionary. Or, if the dictionary on MacOS is system-wide and not limited to specific apps, how to bulk import words into the MacOS dictionary. However, I'd also guess that if it is possible to do any such bulk update, it is a pretty well documented process and you would start the process by researching it yourself. The source of any such dictionary is off topic here, but how to import it, if you are unable to find or follow a guide for it, would be on topic.

@music2myear - Understood, I will look into this. Just to be clear, you are not suggesting the import of a dictionary, but rather the bulk import of words into a preexisting dictionary? For the sake of my own researching: Is "bulk import" the technical term for the process in this context? Is there a technical term for the information contained in a dictionary, or would it just be "words"?

From some research I did yesterday, it appears MacOS uses discrete (separate) dictionaries and has a mechanism to add more. But it also has the ability to add individual words. "Bulk" just means that: in a lot larger than one, but all at once, not requiring individual action for each word. And "Import" is just a convenient word that means to bring in, by whatever means are contextually important. It is not a technical term, but it clearly conveys what is required, and it is likely to be how others have asked similar questions online, and is what I'd use for searching.
